# based on selection display items in second spinner

Tags: android

i am trying to get states in second spinner based on selection in first spinner.if i select india getting all the states but i don't want like that,i need only india states,please help me.below pasted my code

```
package com.example.sankar.machinetest;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private Spinner countrySpinner, stateSpinner, citySpinner;
    private TextView cityCodeTextView;
    private Button submitButton;
    private ArrayList<String> country_list, state_list, city_list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.county);
        stateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.states);
        citySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city);

        country_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        state_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        city_list = new ArrayList<String>();


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJsonFromAsset());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("countries");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject countries_object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String country_name = countries_object.getString("name");
                String country_code = countries_object.getString("countryCode");
                country_list.add(country_name);

                JSONArray states_array = countries_object.getJSONArray("states");

                for (int j = 0; j < states_array.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject states_object = states_array.getJSONObject(j);
                    String state_name = states_object.getString("name");
                    state_list.add(state_name);

                    JSONArray city_array = states_object.getJSONArray("cities");
                    for (int k = 0; k < city_array.length(); k++) {
                        JSONObject city_object = city_array.getJSONObject(k);
                        String city_name = city_object.getString("name");
                        String city_code = city_object.getString("code");
                        city_list.add(city_name);

                    }

                }

            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> country_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, country_list);
            countrySpinner.setAdapter(country_adapter);

            ArrayAdapter<String> city_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, city_list);
            citySpinner.setAdapter(city_adapter);
            countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



    public String loadJsonFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("countries.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            if (position==0) {

                ArrayAdapter<String> state_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, state_list);
                stateSpinner.setAdapter(state_adapter);


            }

    }



    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

and my json is

```
    {
  "countries": [{
    "name": "India",
    "countryCode": "91",
    "states": [{
      "name": "Kerala",
      "cities": [{
        "name": "Thrissur",
        "code": "680111"
      }, {
        "name": "Kochi",
        "code": "680222"
      }, {
        "name": "Trivandrum",
        "code": "680333"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "TamilNadu",
      "cities": [{
        "name": "Chennai",
        "code": "380111"
      }, {
        "name": "Coimbatore",
        "code": "380222"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Germany",
    "countryCode": "49",
    "states": [{
      "name": "Bayern",
      "cities": [{
        "name": "Nurnburg",
        "code": "123"
      }, {
        "name": "Munich",
        "code": "125"
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "Berlin",
      "cities": [{
        "name": "Berlin",
        "code": "223"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: could you post your adapter code?

Comment: thanks,adapter code is included in above code only.

Comment: I need states based on country selection and based on states i want cities,please help me

Comment: You should create java class having same structure as your json data. And then populate the spinner. This way you can get the state and city for the particular country selected inside country spinner.

Comment: hi, can u tell me where u have use URL for json..

Comment: i, did u got ur answer, as i also wanted the same, i m also having 3 spinner , if i check india i shud get only indian state and according to that cities...plz help if u got the correct answer

Comment: follow the answer @android_hub

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public class Country {

    private String name;
    private String code;
    private List<State> states;

    public Country(String name, String code, List<State> states) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.states = states;
    }

   public String getName() {
        return name;
   }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public List<State> getStates() {
        return states;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class State {

    private String name;
    private List<City> cities;

    public State(String name, List<City> cities) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cities = cities;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<City> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class City {

    private String name;
    private String code;

    public City(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then build your data from JSON like this

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(loadJsonFromAsset());
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("countries");

        List<Country> countries;
        List<City> cities;
        List<State> states;

        countries = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject countries_object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // get country name and code
            String country_name = countries_object.getString("name");
            String country_code = countries_object.getString("countryCode");

            // get country states
            JSONArray states_array = countries_object.getJSONArray("states");
            states = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j < states_array.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject states_object = states_array.getJSONObject(j);
                // get state name
                String state_name = states_object.getString("name");
                // get all city for this state
                JSONArray city_array = states_object.getJSONArray("cities");
                cities = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int k = 0; k < city_array.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject city_object = city_array.getJSONObject(k);
                    // get city name and code
                    String city_name = city_object.getString("name");
                    String city_code = city_object.getString("code");
                    // add new city
                    cities.add(new City(city_name, city_code));
                }
                // add new state with cities
                states.add(new State(state_name, cities));
            }
            countries.add(new Country(country_name, country_code, states));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<Country> country_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countries);
        country_adapter.setAdapter(mCountryAdapter);
        country_adapter.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And finally

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    Country country = (Country) mCountrySpinner.getSelectedItem();
    mStateSpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, country.getStates()));
}
```

Comment: whts the name of that class where u r specifying country , state and city

Comment: hi @android_hub..can u tell me where to define this public class country , city and state...n in which class..kindly help

Comment: Those are all independent classes you can define them within the same package of your activity or different, which ever suits you

Comment: and how can we define our url

Comment: from thr json data will come..m new to android ...cud u tell me plz

Comment: if i m declaring in same activity its creating error...so i need to make 3 java class for each one?

Comment: Yes 3 classes for each. And i can't help you without your code and how you have implemented. Update your question with code.

Comment: hi, @android hub, can i hav ur email id, i will send u my code..bcoz i need to change smthin in my code..its taking time

Comment: @z.al As much as i can help but sorry i can't share personal info here

Comment: shud i tell u mine..thr u can send me msg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133737/discussion-between-z-al-and-android-hub).

Comment: c first is my country according to that i am having city and follow by location

Answer (score 0):

```
String countryCode = null;

You can call your second spinner in onItemSelected method.

countryCode = countrySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

// call your second adapter 

before populate state list

HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hmap.put(country_code, stateName);
```

Comment: Thanks,but where can i pass this coutryCode.

Comment: You did not add any country code when populate state.

Comment: HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: hi, did u got ur answer, as i also wanted the same, i m also having 3 spinner , if i check india i shud get only indian state and according to that cities...plz help if u got the correct answer