# How to populate 2 spinner based on selection of 1 spinner where data comes from server in android?

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I am new to android and i want to make 3 spinner , 1 is country , 2 is city and 3rd is location.The data should come from server through JSON.
If i select country example India then by selection of India i should get Mumbai and based on that in Location i should get Juhu.The spinner should change according to change of 1st spinner.I have already done this code but the items are coming from array string but now i want item  from server through Json parsing.I am unable to get any good example of it.Kindly help

Comment: use `Retrofit 2` or `Volley` library to parse `JSON`  into `List` then pass them to the spinner adapter

Comment: Are you able to get the data from server ?

Comment: i know how to get data from server...but how to fix this issue like if i select i spinner other will change according to 1 spinner..

Comment: i have done this code manually like i have added the items in string array but now items shud come from server...thst d issue

Comment: Create java classes for country containing list of states and states having list of cities and then populate the spinner. Then in item selected method get the country and from that their particular states and cities

Comment: i need items from server

Comment: i have already made this program manually where i added country city and location but now i want it server based

Comment: earlier i have added items in array but now i want to make it server based so in future user can add more items according to the needs

Comment: You already getting JSON from server right? Which you parse to Country and states and so on. So when item is selected in country spinner make a server call or parse the JSON to get related info and then populate the other spinners accordingly.

Comment: do u have any example ,i will get more idea from that...

Comment: [Check if this can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787110/based-on-selection-display-items-in-second-spinner/41788426#41788426)

Comment: thx for help i will chk it

Comment: but can u tell me where he is using URL , we need to put URL also for json? can u tell me